# Cannot find g++ after msys2 install

Tags: windows-11, visual-studio-code, c++, mingw, g++

I want to install g++ so I can compile and run C++ code in VScode.

I started by trying to follow the VSCode-provided [guide](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/cpp/config-mingw) which states I need to install mysys.

I tried installing [msys2](https://www.msys2.org/) per the given instructions, but running `g++ --version` in Command Prompt returned `'g++' is not recognized`.

I then tried adding `C:\msys64\mingw64\bin` to the `Path` variable under '*User Variables for Solebay*' (Windows 11, System>About>Advanced System Settings>Environment Variables). g++ was still not found.

**Second approach:**

As seen [here](https://gorvgoyl.medium.com/run-debug-intellisense-c-c-in-vscode-within-5-minutes-3ed956e059d6) I tried unzipping [MinGW64.zip](https://github.com/GorvGoyl/MinGW64/releases) directly into `C:\` as well as adding `C:\MinGW64\bin` to my path. Again, g++ is not recognised.

This was easy on Ubuntu but I'm lost with Windows. What on earth am I doing?

Answer (score 1):

You have to run..

```
pacman -S --needed base-devel mingw-w64-x86_64-toolchain
```

..in msys after it is installed.

You may need to start a new project or restart the computer to instigate changes in VScode.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).